# wp custom table - count wp rows returns 0

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I made a custom wp table,
but there is a problem. Count rows doesn't work carefully.

All of this variable return 0,
but you can see in my table we have 3 record with read = 1.

(read=1 : read ,read = 2 : unread)

```
$table_name    = $wpdb->prefix . 'inbox';

$inbox_rows = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name where type= 1 ");
$unread1 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE 'read'= 1 and type = 1 ");
$unread2 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE 'read'= 1 and type = 2 ");
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name where  'read'= 1 ");

/*
|------|------|
| read | type | both of them are int (in phpmyadmin)
|------|------|
|   2  |  1   |
|------|------|
|   1  |  1   |
|------|------|
|   1  |  2   |
|------|------|
|   1  |  1   |
|------|------|

*/
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think u missing the $wpdb global declare like below code:

```
 global $wpdb;
    $table_name    = $wpdb->prefix . 'index';
    $inbox_rows = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name where type= 1 ");
```